# The history tag has no wiki summary?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-tag

Clicking any of the tags below the answers redirects the user to the tag's Wiki page but displays the following message:

> The history tag has no wiki summary,
>   would you like to help us create it?

Is this normal? It think it should display the summary of questions with that same tag?

A bug perhaps?

Comment: Can you give us the URL of the page you are seeing the bug on? It might help with debugging (and/or a screenshot)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysticism-kabbalah should show not just wiki but recent questions which are tagged "mysticism-kabbalah"

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the [history](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag, you do see a list of all the questions tagged thus. You're right that there's no wiki there yet, but that's just because no one's taken the time to write one! Since we got the tag-wiki feature a few weeks ago, some members of the community have started wikis for some of the tags, but most of them have not been addressed yet. If you have some extra time that you want to spend making this site more awesome, go ahead and start some wikis!

Comment: PS: I started the history wiki.